# Using elementFromPoint on an SVG object to detect a drop target

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, svg

I've come slightly unstuck trying to implement a drag / drop on to an SVG stage, this works fine in everything but IE11 which always returns NULL, I can reference nodes within the SVG by ID so I don't think its a cross-origin issue;

HTML:

```
<object id="SVGObject" width="960px" height="550px" type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/images/stage.svg"></object>
```

Javascript:

```
var SVG = document.getElementById('SVGObject');
var SVGDOM = SVG.contentDocument;
var test = SVGDOM.elementFromPoint(x, y); // returns NULL in IE11
```

Comment: https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/458

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I was hopeful but unfortunately that didn't work`unable to get property of undefined or null reference`

Comment: @chris did you wait for the object element's onload event to fire?

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not explicitly waiting for it but the listener that catches the touch-end event doesn't get called until its loaded and I can get elements from within the SVG using getElementById it seems to be an IE specific bug?